# Create a fragment many times with different data and add to back stack

Tags: java, android, fragment, onbackpressed

I create one fragment with many items because the number of items is not known I want when clicked in every item that same fragment recreate it(like child fragment) and add to back stack With information about each specific item
and when back pressed pop in back stack.
(A fragment is often created with new information and added to the back stack and pop)
Any one can help me?

Comment: Are these screens always stacked on top of eachother (i.e. A1->A2->A3) or can there be different screens inbetween (i.e. A1->A2->B->A3)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @rezayi. It seems you are looking for others to solve your problem. 
Please take the tour and add some detail to your post as to what you have tried so far that isn't working (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
There is likely a bunch of answers here on StackOverflow that will help you implement a solution to your required design.